# Function caller (to multiple receivers) interface

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, reflection, duck-typing

This class is designed to call a similar function of multiple objects of multiple classes using a single interface (it is not for calling functions that return a value).

A potential usage will be sending same data to multiple writers (log writer, HTML generator and styled printer to console).

Tested with **Python 3.4.2**

I've also included a test/example in the below code:

```
"""
caller module:
Contains Caller class - call multiple other classes or modules with
similar function definitions, (it is not for calling functions that 
returns a value)

Author : Bhathiya Perera
"""
class Caller():
    """call other classes or modules with
       similar function definitions"""
    def __init__(self, *receivers):
        """Initialize

        Parameters :                    
            receivers - va-arg receivers (can be objects, modules,
                        another caller , ....)    
        """
        self._names = []
        self._receivers = receivers

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        """Get attribute of a given name
        This will return 'self' therefore it can be called later
        """    
        self._names.append(name)
        return self

    def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
        """This class is callable with any arguments or key-value arguments
        It will then be posted to all receivers
        """
        if len(self._names) == 0:
            raise Exception("Cannot call")

        method_name = self._names.pop()
        for receiver in self._receivers:
            method = getattr(receiver, method_name)
            method(*args, **kw)

        return self

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # -------------------------------------------------
    # Test its usage
    class Receiver1():
        def a(self, arg):
            print ("Receiver1 - a", arg)

        def b(self, arg):
            print ("Receiver1 - b", arg)       

    class Receiver2():
        def a(self, arg):
            print ("Receiver2 - a", arg)

        def b(self, arg):
            print ("Receiver2 - b", arg)

    class Receiver3():
        def a(self, arg):
            print ("Receiver3 - a", arg)

        def b(self, arg):
            print ("Receiver3 - b", arg)

    c = Caller(Receiver3())
    d = Caller(Receiver1(), Receiver2(), c)  
    d.a("hello a")
    d.b("hello b")
    print ("-----")
    d.a.b.a.b.a.b.a("a")("b")("c")("d")("e")("f")("g")
```

If it was executed as a module it will print:

> ```
> Receiver1 - a hello a
> Receiver2 - a hello a
> Receiver3 - a hello a
> Receiver1 - b hello b
> Receiver2 - b hello b
> Receiver3 - b hello b
> -----
> Receiver1 - a a
> Receiver2 - a a
> Receiver3 - a a
> Receiver1 - b b
> Receiver2 - b b
> Receiver3 - b b
> Receiver1 - a c
> Receiver2 - a c
> Receiver3 - a c
> Receiver1 - b d
> Receiver2 - b d
> Receiver3 - b d
> Receiver1 - a e
> Receiver2 - a e
> Receiver3 - a e
> Receiver1 - b f
> Receiver2 - b f
> Receiver3 - b f
> Receiver1 - a g
> Receiver2 - a g
> Receiver3 - a g
> ```

Review for Python conventions and anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly,
the purpose of `Caller` seems to be to call a function on multiple objects.
It works like this:

- Construct a `Caller x` by passing 1 or more objects in the constructor
- Call any method `m` on `x`, and it will be dispatched to method `m` of all objects

Right? The docstring doesn't explain this very well.
`CallDispatcher` might be a better name.

My impression is that you're discovering powerful features of Python,
and you're trying to use them *because you can*,
not because you have a concrete purpose.
Sort of like an exercise, not for real-life use.

It seems to me that `__getattr__` is seriously abused.
I don't have experience overriding this method,
but I would guess it's designed to implement getters dynamically.
First of all,
adding getters dynamically seems like a hack that should be used with extreme care,
including a good justification that it's the best option.
Secondly,
instead of behaving as a getter,
this implementation *mutates* the object and returns `self`.
I see you did that to make chaining and currying possible,
it's interesting, but it seems a misuse of the language.

Another thing I don't like about the approach is the heavy dependence on [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).
The objects that can be used with `Caller` don't have to follow a well-defined interface,
they can be anything.
The user just has to make sure that when they call a `.hello` function on a `Caller` object,
all the objects inside have a `.hello` function defined.
It's great that Python let's us do this kind of thing,
but it doesn't mean that we should.
I prefer to have well-defined and well-documented interfaces,
with a list of legitimate methods that I'm allowed to call.

#### Python conventions

Instead of:

> ```
> class Caller():
> ```

The class should be declared as:

```
class Caller:
```

Instead of:

> ```
>     if len(self._names) == 0:
> ```

The Pythonic way:

```
    if not self._names:
```

Instead of:

> ```
>         print ("Receiver3 - b", arg)
> ```

There should be no space before the opening paren:

```
        print("Receiver3 - b", arg)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have been doing too much Python coding without getting any reviews. Also I have trouble writing module level doc-string, they just end up being a copy of Classes' doc strings.

Comment: There's no such thing as too much Python coding ;-) Keep it up!

Answer (score 1):

The idea of using `__getattr__` to build a stack of methods to call feels strange to me, and your usage example `d.a.b.a.b.a.b.a("a")("b")("c")("d")("e")("f")("g")` does nothing to convince me otherwise. Also, if I do this

```
a = d.a
b = d.b
a("a")
b("b")
```

I get this result:

```
Receiver1 - b a
Receiver2 - b a
Receiver3 - b a
Receiver1 - a b
Receiver2 - a b
Receiver3 - a b
```

Instead, I suggest returning just a callable from `__getattr__`, eg. like this:

```
class Caller():

    def __init__(self, *receivers):
        self._receivers = receivers

    def __getattr__(self, method_name):
        def f(*args, **kw):
            for receiver in self._receivers:
                method = getattr(receiver, method_name)
                method(*args, **kw)   
        return f
```